# MySQL "ANY IN" query?

Tags: mysql, any, sql-in

Is there any short way to do something like this in MySQL:

```
WHERE s.loc1 IN ("A", "B", "C", "D") 
   OR s.loc2 IN ("A", "B", "C", "D") 
   OR s.loc3 IN ("A", "B", "C", "D");
```

without repeating the ("A", "B", "C", "D") bit (and preferably in such a way that this list is still suppliable via @param)? Sadly, the syntax of (s.loc1, s.loc2, s.loc3) IN (blah) only seems to work for AND's instead of OR's.

The ideal solution would look something like:

```
WHERE (s.loc1, s.loc2, s.loc3) ANY IN ("A", "B", "C", "D");
```

Comment: OR's should be working...  Can you provide Minimally Complete and Verifable Example  (MVCE) which shows the OR's not working and indicate what version of mySQL this is?  Just a sample create table with loc1,2,3 and sample data,  Perhaps you need to be using apostrophe instead of quote?

Comment: Short answer: there's no syntax for merging your three "in/or" clauses into a single , shoter clause.

Comment: can add the IN table to from and compare equals tho!

Comment: Oh I get it now.... eliminate the repetition of the in.  Well you could but I think the maintenance is cleaner your way as it's easy to see what you want. `SELECT Distinct s.*
FROM SO52121085 s
CROSS JOIN (SELECT "A" x UNION ALL 
            SELECT "B" x UNION ALL 
            SELECT "C" x UNION ALL 
            SELECT "D" x) Val
WHERE s.loc1 = x or s.loc2 = x or S.LOC3 = x;` [DEMO](http://rextester.com/RDRR17263)  now if A, B, C, D are in a table we can eliminate the unions and simply select where.

Comment: What does "like this" mean? Something involving not repeating expressions?

Answer (score 1):

You could query from a table generated (that is, a table subquery or a [derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html)) from a union of the values:

```
select
    *
from (
    (select loc1 as loc, s.* from s)
    union
    (select loc2 as loc, s.* from s)
    union
    (select loc3 as loc, s.* from s)
) t
where
    t.loc in ("A","B","C","D");
```

Running the above query yields:

```
+-----+------+------+------+
| loc | loc1 | loc2 | loc3 |
+-----+------+------+------+
| A   | A    | 2    | 3    |
| D   | D    | 2    | 3    |
| B   | 1    | B    | 3    |
| C   | 1    | 2    | C    |
+-----+------+------+------+
```

when run on this made up data:

```
drop table if exists s;
create table s (
    loc1 varchar(255) not null,
    loc2 varchar(255) not null,
    loc3 varchar(255) not null
);
insert into s values
("1","2","3"),
("A","2","3"),
("1","B","3"),
("1","2","C"),
("D","2","3");
```

See also a [demo version](http://rextester.com/XXP97130)